# Creating a form from mysql_fetch_array query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, fetch

I have a field in a MySQL database called 'location' - it serves up North, South, East, West only.

I have used this code to get only the 4 results that are distinct:

```
$query_form = "SELECT DISTINCT location FROM hotel ORDER BY location ASC";
$result_form = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_form) or die('die query error');
$row_form = mysql_fetch_array($result_form, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

I wanted to use the four results from this query to populate a table such that:

```
<option value='1'>North</option>
<option value='2'>South</option>
<option value='3'>East</option>
<option value='4'>West</option>
```

I have used this:

```
foreach ($row_form['location'] as $k => $v) {
    echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>\n';
    }
```

but I fear that my approach will not work - with regret, I am a noob and unable to work out what is wrong!

Thanks

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_assoc();` or change to `mysql_fetch_array($result_form, MYSQL_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) will only *(quoting the manual, emphasis mine)* :

> Fetch **a result row** as an
> associative array, a numeric array, or
> both

So, you'll have to call this function several times -- actually, once per row *(so, here, 4 times)*.

This is normally done with a loop, looping while you get results.

In your case, you'll probably want to use something that looks like this :

```
$lineCounter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_form, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    // Use your row, here.
    // For instance : $row['location']
    // And you can use the $lineCounter variable, to keep track of the current line number.
    $lineCounter++;
}
```

Notes :

- I used `MYSQL_ASSOC`, to get an associative array for each row : I think it's easier to work this way.
- In the body of the `while` loop, you can use the `$row` associative array, indexed by column name.

As a sidenote, when injecting data (such as strings) in some HTML code, you should escape the output properly, to avoid HTML injections.

See, for a solution, the [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQLI_NUM actually returns the fields with numeric indices. As per your requirement, I believe, it wont really help in having `<option value="x">..`

[Check this link about what MYSQLI_NUM actually does: What does MYSQLI_NUM mean and do?

Now, in your code, you need to modify as follows:

```
$i=1;
while ($row_form=mysql_fetch_array($result_form, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $row_form['location'] . '</option>\n';
    $i++;
}
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in another answer here, you really need to have a loop construct for retrieving each row out from the database. One single `mysql_fetch_array(..)` will give you only one row. You need to iterate in a loop, till the function returns a valid row.

Check how the function works: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php